# Python AST: How to get the children of a node

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on Python 2.6.5.

Given a Abstract Syntax Tree, I want to obtain its children.

Most StackOverflow posts discuss `ast.NodeVisitor` and the methods defined in it: `visit()`, `generic_visit()`.
However, `visit()` and `generic_visit()` do not give the children, rather they directly apply the function recursively on them.

Can someone please write a short code or so to demonstrate it?
Does there exist a predefined function in python library for the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attaributes containing the node's children depend on the type of syntax the node represents.  Every node class also has a special `_fields` attribute, that lists the attribute names for the child nodes that class has. For instance,

```
>>> ast.parse('5+a')
<_ast.Module object at 0x02C1F730>
>>> ast.parse('5+a').body
[<_ast.Expr object at 0x02C1FF50>]
>>> ast.parse('5+a').body[0]
<_ast.Expr object at 0x02C1FBF0>
>>> ast.parse('5+a').body[0]._fields
('value',)
>>> ast.parse('5+a').body[0].value
<_ast.BinOp object at 0x02C1FF90>
>>> ast.parse('5+a').body[0].value._fields
('left', 'op', 'right')
>>> ast.parse('5+a').body[0].value.left
<_ast.Num object at 0x02C1FB70>
```

and so on.

*Edit, to clarify what's going on*

Before going any further, take a glance at the [CPython Abstract Grammar](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar)

Consider:

```
>>> type(ast.parse('5+a'))
<class '_ast.Module'>
```

In fact, if you look at the grammar, the first production rule is for Module.  It appears to take a sequence of statements, as an argument called body.

```
>>> ast.parse('5+a')._fields
('body',)
>>> ast.parse('5+a').body
[<_ast.Expr object at 0x02E965B0>]
```

The `_fields` attribute of the AST is just "body", and the body attribute is a sequence of AST nodes.  Back to the grammar, looking in the production rules for `stmt`, we see that `Expr` takes a single expr, named `value`

```
>>> ast.parse('5+a').body[0].value
<_ast.BinOp object at 0x02E96330>
```

If we look up the definition for BinOp, we see that it takes 3 different arguments, left, op and right.  You should be able to proceed from there, I hope.

Comment: thanks for your reply!  However I haven't understood it yet properly... so node._fields will give the children of that particular node? (in form of a tupple?).... then what does body and value signify? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The `ast` module provides an `iter_child_nodes` function you might find useful.

```
def iter_child_nodes(node):                                                    
    """                                                                        
    Yield all direct child nodes of *node*, that is, all fields that are nodes 
    and all items of fields that are lists of nodes.                           
    """                                                                        
    for name, field in iter_fields(node):                                      
        if isinstance(field, AST):                                             
            yield field                                                        
        elif isinstance(field, list):                                          
            for item in field:                                                 
                if isinstance(item, AST):                                      
                    yield item                                                 

                                                                               `
```